# C++ sound repeating with mmstream

Tags: c++, audio, repeat

I'm not sure why, but recently my C++ OpenGL sound streams using mmstream library keeps repeating even though the if statements controlling them are false (Checked using Break Points)

Here's a snippet of code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);  
    glutGameModeString("1280x768:32@75");
    glutEnterGameMode();
    init();
    glutIdleFunc(idle);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutReshapeFunc(resize);
    glutKeyboardFunc(keyboard);
    glutDisplayFunc(myDisplay);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouseMove);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

and

```
void mouseMove(int x, int y)
{
    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if (!level1.levelOneActive[i])
        {
            if(x >= originX && x <= ((windowW + resizeWindowW) * 0.25) && y >= originY && y <= (windowH + resizeWindowH))
            {
                useOnce = true;
                PlaySound(TEXT("newGame.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);
                useOnce = false;
            }

            if(x >= originX + ((windowW + resizeWindowW) * 0.25) && x <= ((windowW + resizeWindowW) * 0.5) && y >= originY && y <= (windowH + resizeWindowH))
            {
                useOnce = true;
                PlaySound(TEXT("loadGame.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);
                useOnce = false;
            }

            if(x >= originX + ((windowW + resizeWindowW) * 0.5) && x <= ((windowW + resizeWindowW) * 0.75) && y >= originY && y <= (windowH + resizeWindowH))
            {
                useOnce = true;
                PlaySound(TEXT("options.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);
                useOnce = false;
            }

            if(x >= originX + ((windowW + resizeWindowW) * 0.75) && x <= (windowW + resizeWindowW) && y >= originY && y <= (windowH + resizeWindowH))
            {
                useOnce = true;
                PlaySound(TEXT("exitGame.wav"), NULL, SND_FILENAME | SND_SYNC);
                useOnce = false;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT: Here's the header file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "gl\glut.h"
#include "levelOne.h"
#include "levelTwo.h"
#include "player.h"
#include "trap.h"
#include <mmstream.h>
using namespace std;

levelOne level1;
levelTwo level2;
player player1;
trap t1;
int windowW = 500, windowH = 500, timer = 60;
int resizeWindowW = 0, resizeWindowH = 0;
int originX = 0, originY = 0, i;
bool useOnce = false;
```

Comment: Why is this tagged OpenGL and why does it mention OpenGL in the title... OpenGL has nothing to do with sound!

Comment: @Vallentin: Just in case its OpenGL that's causing this

Comment: how do you imagine that OpenGL could cause this? since OpenGL has nothing to do with audio in any way or form.

Comment: @Vallentin: I don't know. Want me to remove the tag then?